# How can I write a function which gets a Map[Char, Int] as an input and makes a Set[Case Class]?

Tags: scala, dictionary

Found this stepik task and have no idea what to do:

> Write a function which gets a Map[Char, Int] as an input and makes a Set[LetterTree] (LetterTree is the case class below), in which from each (c,w) map entry, we make a LetterLevel(c,w), then we then put it in the said Set[LetterTree].

````
trait LetterTree {
  def weight: Int
}

case class LetterLevel(ch: Char, weight: Int) extends LetterTree

object TreeBuild extends App {
  def TreeSetBuild(freqs: Map[Char,Int]): Set[LetterTree] = ???```
}
````

Comment: `def foo(m: Map[Char, Int]) = m.map { case (k,v) => LeterLevel(k,v) }.toSet`  ... You have now advanced to the level 2! :D

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `tupled` to construct `LetterLevel` instances from the tuple elements of the `Map`:

```
object TreeBuild extends App {
  def treeSetBuild(freqs: Map[Char,Int]): Set[LetterTree] =
    freqs.map(LetterLevel.tupled).toSet
}

TreeBuild.treeSetBuild(Map('a'->1, 'b'->2, 'c'->3))
// res1: Set[LetterTree] = Set(LetterLevel(a,1), LetterLevel(b,2), LetterLevel(c,3))
```

Comment: Not a problem.  RE: your "no idea what to do" remark, perhaps it's an indicator the exercise you're trying to work on consists of Scala topics you haven't commanded.  If you haven't done so, consider picking a good Scala programming book such as `Programming in Scala` by Odersky, et al, to get a good grasp of the language's basics.